# Configuring visual studio with CPLEX in mac OS

Tags: macos, visual-studio, cplex

I just got my first MacBook after being a windows user for my entire life. I could not find any instruction about how Configure MS Visual Studio to use IBM CPLEX. is it even possible? I know I can configure Xcode but is there a way to use MS visual studio?

Comment: Hi, have you had a look at https://www.leandro-coelho.com/how-to-configure-ibm-cplex-with-apple-xcode/ ?

Comment: yes. that is for Xcode configuration. I need it for Visual Studio